# I am having troubles with my gaming character code on JavaScript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I preparing for Game Jam in my school and came across a problem. In this code I am trying to make it so when you press the right arrow key, it moves the character right. But the function is making it move from the right instead of right.

Here is my code---

```
var main = function() {
    var moveRight = function() {}
    var wall = function() {
        wall = $('.header')
    }
    $(document).keypress(function(event) {
        if(event.which === 32) {
        $('.header').animate({
            bottom: "-31px"
            },1000)
        }
    });   
    $(document).keydown(function(event) {
        if(event.which === 39) {
            $('.character').animate({
                right: "400px"
            },1000)    
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

The problem is in here somewhere---

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    if(event.which === 39) {
        $('.character').animate({
            right: "400px"
        },1000)    
    }
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why are the two pieces of code different? The first one looks wrong. "right: 400px" is going to set the right edge to 400px from the right edge of whatever it is contained in, not move it to the right 400px.

Comment: You should be moving your character in opposite direction.

Answer (score 1):

In css the `right` property describes the *amount of distance between the right side of the element, and the right side of its container*. Consider a person standing between a "left wall" and a "right wall". In css, if they have `right: 0`, their right side is touching the right wall. With `right: 3px`, their right side is 3 pixels from that wall. As you can see, **increasing `right` moves elements LEFT**. You are probably interested in using the `left` attribute instead of `right`:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.which === 39) {
        $('.character').animate({ left: "400px" }, 1000);
    }
});
```

## Note

While it has some applications, mixing `left` and `right` properties is probably not a good idea in your specific situation. Ensure that you never use the `right` property any more, and replace every instance of the usage of `right` with `left` instead!